# Disable a Gridview position in a row in Android

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have tried all my best to look for solution everywhere including SO but it seems that I am not getting anywhere and I decided to ask the question to see if I can get someone that will help me out on this. OK here is what I am trying to do:

I have a GridView of 4 columns and 4 rows. The GridView is filled with images using imageAdapter. When an image is selected in a row the image in that position changes to another image and when it is selected (Deselected) again it changes back to the previous image. That is fine. what I am trying to do now is that when a position is selected, I want to disable all other position until the selected position is deselected by clicking on it again. In essence I want to make sure that no two positions can be selected at the same time. I have tried my best but this seems a bit impossible for now. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong. When the user select a position, in a row others don't get disabled. Below is my code: Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you for your anticipated help.

private OnItemClickListener onGridItemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

     //if (v == null) return;  //Just added 03/04/2013

    int rowOfSelectedItem =  getRowInGrid(position);
    Log.i(TAG, "Selected View is : "+v.getId()+" (Id arg = "+id+")- Position is "+ position+" Row is = "+rowOfSelectedItem);

    switch(rowOfSelectedItem){
    case 1:
        //iterate through first row items and check if any of the items was selected before
        for(int x=2; x < 4; x++){
            //
            Object tag = ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).getTag();
            Log.i(TAG, "This is : "+ x + "TAG is " + tag);
            if(tag ==null || !Boolean.valueOf(tag.toString())){
                //disable clicking so the user cannot select another image on same row
                ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).setClickable(false);
                ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).setEnabled(false);
                Log.i(TAG, "This is : "+ x + tag);

            }


        }
        break;
    case 2:

        for(int x=4; x < 8; x++){
            //
            Object tag = ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).getTag(); 
            if(tag ==null || !Boolean.valueOf(tag.toString())){
                //disable clicking so the user cannot select another image on same row
                ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).setClickable(false);
                ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).setEnabled(false);

            }
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        for(int x=8; x < 12; x++){
            //
            Object tag = ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).getTag(); 
            if(tag ==null || !Boolean.valueOf(tag.toString())){
                //disable clicking so the user cannot select another image on same row
                ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).setClickable(false);
                ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).setEnabled(false);

            }
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        for(int x=12; x < 16; x++){
            //
            Object tag = ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).getTag(); 
            if(tag ==null || !Boolean.valueOf(tag.toString())){
                //disable clicking so the user cannot select another image on same row
                ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).setClickable(false);
                ((ImageView)gridView.getChildAt(x)).setEnabled(false);

            }
        }
        break;
    }
```

private int getRowInGrid(int position){

```
    if(position <= 3){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(position <=7){
        return 2;
    }
    else if(position <= 11){
        return 3;
    }
    else if(position <= 15){
        return 4;
    }
    else{ return -1;}
}
```